# How to create first_or_redirect() like first_or_404() in flask application

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app with flask login. I want to protect one user from accessing another user's data.

This returns error, which is fine, but I would like to have a redirect to home instead.

```
@login_required
def myurl(po_id):
current_po = Purchaseorder.query.filter_by(id=po_id, owner=current_user.id)\
    .first_or_404()
# delete edit ..
```

I tried also:

```
@login_required
def myurl(po_id):
current_po = Purchaseorder.query.filter_by(id=po_id).first()
if current_po.owner!=current_user.id:
    redirect ...
```

But seems too much writing every time.

Is there a solution for that and maybe also for .all() ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an inbuilt method, but you could do `current_po = Purchaseorder.query.filter_by(id=po_id, owner=current_user.id).first() or redirect(...)`

Comment: @Henry oh, so if None is returned it goes redirect ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write your own decorator and control if user was authorized or not:

```py
from functools import wraps

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session


app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'


def wrapper_redirect(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        if not session.get("login"):
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_func


@app.route("/")
def index():
    session["login"] = True  # log in

    return "<h1>index page</h1>"


@app.route("/test")
@wrapper_redirect
def hello_world():
    if session.get("login"):
        del session["login"]  # log out
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9999)
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I have that, but what I mean is if a record does not belong to the user.

Comment: @TomasAm I am sorry, can you clarify what do you mean under record does not belong to the user? You can specify any situation if you create your own decorator.

Comment: Simply website.com/purchase/1 belongs to user 1 and user 2 types this url.

Comment: @TomasAm If the website is your app you can implement the logic in your decorators

Comment: So I would need decorators with parameters probably? Queried record in database has a collumn 'owner'. The only way to check if the user is owner of the record is first to make query of that record and compare to current user's id. Not sure if you can do that in decorator.

Comment: @TomasAm authorization usually works the following way you store some user id as JWT token or probably smth else in encryption cookie or in request header, than when you get request from user you can check the id in some middleware or write decorator which does it and check that token / id / smth else is valid, then get additional info about user (if you need it) from some database. I hope that my explanation helped.